# webbrowser + yandex browser

Tags: python, webbrowser, яндекс-браузер

Я работаю с библиотекой webbrowser и она не может открывать страницы в Yandex browser. Есть ли возможность это исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Мне было не сложно, я за вас по гуглил

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.register('Yandex', None, webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser('полный путь к яндексу браузеру который заканчивается на .exe'))
webbrowser.get('Yandex').open_new_tab('vk.com')
```

еще одно решение
Установить Yandex brauser как браузер по умолчанию

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('https://vk.com')
```

Comment: он уже как браузер по умолчанию, когда я ваш 2 код запускаю не происходит от слова ничего, а про путь я знал, но путь - это кастыль.

Comment: Так сделайте так чтоб чтоб путь не был костылем. На пример вытачит путь из реестра. Если Yandex установлен по дефолту, то путь будет всегда известен.